# Does the Apple Adventure loadSceneAssets completion handler run on completion?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, sprite-kit

The code below is taken from the Apple Sprite Kit Adventure example. The code is worded in such a way to suggest that the method [self loadSceneAssets]; is executed in the background and on completion the supplied handler block is executed back on the main thread.

My question is: does it really work this way as I can't see the mechanism that allows for the block to run **after** the completion of loadSceneAssets. Basically if loadSceneAssets takes 15secs to complete will the supplied block wait 15 secs then run or will it start running as soon as the loadSceneAsset method starts?

***NOTE**: The idea behind this is that the assets (SKTextures, SKSpriteNodes etc.) for the scene are loaded and made ready before the scene is presented for display.*

```
#pragma mark - Shared Assets
+ (void)loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:(APAAssetLoadCompletionHandler)handler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        // Load the shared assets in the background.
        [self loadSceneAssets];

        if (!handler) {
            return;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Call the completion handler back on the main queue.
            handler();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: assets are loaded in an async block, and when the method returns the completion handler (if any) is called

Comment: I see now, [self loadSceneAssets]; and handler(); are both executed consecutively. I was getting confused that [self loadSceneAssets]; and handler(); were both running at the same time, but on different threads. Thank you.

Comment: Each block runs consecutively but may run on a separate thread (when dispatch_async is used for example). So the "loading assets" block runs asynchronously, and when loading is complete the handler block also runs asynchronously.

Comment: Yup got it, thanks Steffen.